# Unity game slowing down when exported as EXE

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Whenever I export my Unity game as an EXE, and as a WebGL as well, the physics slow down. Everything else is fine, like rotation, GUI, etc. But the physics does not work properly.

I have tried to use Fixed Update and Delta Time, but both break the physics. Also, the editor testing doesn't ever slow down, no matter what resolution, scale, etc.

I don't know where to look, and what might be causing the issue. I have looked it up on Google, but all of the other people's answers do not help.

Comment: `I have tried to use Fixed Update and Delta Time, but both break the physics.` Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: On your PC you are most of the time running stuff with 1k frames per second .. on WebGL definitely not .. so something frame-rate dependent could definitely be the case .. if your stuff runs already significantly faster in the editor the change of resolution etc are probably minimal

Comment: @Verpous I have tried using different combos of both for all of my physics stuff, but no matter what I do it stops working in the editor :/ Another issue which might be it is that I tried to make the EXE run in a windowed state, yet it opens and runs full screen even though I think I saved it

Comment: @derHugo I have changed the resolution on the editor and in the game testing window, and it still runs normally.

Comment: @eagleskull14 would you mind showing us a sample of your code - specifically, some of your code which you're using for physics stuff (how you are moving physics objects etc)

Comment: @11belowstudio Yeah, sorry about that, I should have done that earlier, oops! But I currently use on update to check for input, and if there is input, then if the input it horizontal then rotate the player, which works fine in the exported version, but if the input is vertical the set the velocity of the player to the old velocity plus the forward of the player times moveSpeed. This is fine when playing unexported, but the exported version makes it so the player can't go forward or backward, but you can still turn and the other code like sound and UI is fine.

Comment: @eagleskull14 Okay, how are you setting the velocity of the player? Are you doing it by editing the `.velocity` of a `Rigidbody`? (tbf it'll probably be easier for everyone involved if you would just include the code of the `Update()` method itself (or at least the relevant parts of it) in your post)

Comment: @11belowstudio Yeah sorry about the code thing i dont have access to my code rn to copy and paste but yes i do set the velocity of the ridgidbody.

Comment: Still sounds to me like you are doing something frame-rate dependent -> webGL has way less frames per second -> your movement is slower ... `old velocity plus the forward of the player times moveSpeed` .. if you are not using `Time.deltaTime` here this acceleration is frame-rate dependent (more frames = faster acceleration) .. again in the editor you probably have way more frames per second .. probably about a factor 50 so the resolution there has barely any impact

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, I will test this when I get the chance. BTW, can you tell me the code you mean, like the old vel plus the new vel ect, in case mine doesn't want to work so I can see what you would do. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Thanks so much to @derHugo, @Verpous, and @11belowstudio! To fix the issue I had to add in the delta time, but I also had to tweak many variables to way higher floats to make it work the way I wanted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).